# Xcode AdMob's GAD_SIMULATOR_ID undeclared identifier error

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I downloaded  AdMob SDK iOS 7.0.0 yesterday and i followed Google AdMob's iOS guide.

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

request.testDevices= @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"];
```

When I put in the above line I get an Xcode error stating 'Use of undeclared identifier 'GAD_SIMULATOR_ID'

However, on iOS guide in Google's AdMob it states that's how to get a test banner on iOS device. So why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Starting from the SDK version 7.0.0 you no longer need to precise **GAD_SIMULATOR_ID** so as to run test ads in the simulator. It is now done automatically.

Please, have a look at the banner example [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/admob/BannerExample/BannerExample/ViewController.m): it is precised in the comments.

**EDIT:**

From SDK 7.0 to 7.1 you can use **kDFPSimulatorID**

Starting from the SDK 7.2 you can use **kGADSimulatorID**

Comment: No, you're wrong. I'm not talking about the simulator. I know only test banners load on simulator. I'm talking about the device. I followed that iOS guide and i had a real ad banner showing in my app when I wanted a test banner. So there must be another way.

Comment: I only wrote that XCode states "Use of undeclared identifier 'GAD_SIMULATOR_ID", because you don't need to write request.testDevices= @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID]; anymore.
In your case you only need to write directly 
request.testDevices= @[ @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]; This is how i do and i receive test ads in my device.

Comment: I agree with @Jameltheone that this constant is for the simulator only and not the devices, you have to add the device id to the test devices

Comment: Else you can add 'kDFPSimulatorID' instead of GAD_SIMULATOR_ID.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Christeena said it is now "kDFPSimulatorID" with the Google AdMobs SDK update to v7.0.0